# Material-ui timepicker format

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

I am using the following time picker from Material-UI (see link below) and wanted to see whether it was possible to cater for the following format as I need to allow the user to enter 24 hour time as well as to the second:

```
"HH:mm:ss"
```

I have tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
                    <TextField
                        name="time"
                        label="Alarm clock"
                        type="time"
                        defaultValue=""
                        format="HH:mm:ss"
                      />
```

https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/#time-pickers

Please note: I am not able to use [Material-UI Pickers](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/) and need to use the above.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

`material-ui` has a separate repo for the Date time pickers called `material-ui-pickers` .

We can configure 24hr format with seconds as well. Please refer the link

### Update:

`material-ui-pickers` has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/pickers) but has been replaced by [`@mui/x-date-pickers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/x-date-pickers)

The NPM Page above, links to [this documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/)

Comment: I have actually looked at this but I am not able to use this as I need to set the time as null and this repo doesn't allow it - even the datepicker doesn't allow a null date. Based on this, can my question above cater for `HH:Mi:SS` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by simply setting the step value in the TextField:

```
<TextField type="time" value="00:00:00" inputProps={{ step: 1 }} />
```